# Python dictionary with multiple unique values corresponding to a key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 2 lists which correspond to what I would like to be my key:value pairs, for example:

```
list_1 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2] #(key)

list_2 = [x,x,x,y,g,r,t,w,r,r,r,t,f,c,d] #(value)
```

I've (kind of) been able to create a dictionary via: `dict = dict(zip(list_1, [list_2]))`

However the problem with this is that it is only picking up '1' as a key and also results in duplicate entries within the list of values for the key.

Can anyone suggest a way to create a dictionary so that only the unique values from `list_2` are mapped to their corresponding key?

Thanks

EDIT:

output I'm looking for would be one dictionary keyed by 1 and 2 with lists as values containing only the unique values for each i.e.:

```
dict = {1: [x,y,g,r,t,w], 2: [r,t,f,c,d]}
```

Comment: If elements in `list_1` are in order (or at least repeated values are all together) you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Comment: Can you define what your ideal output would look like, to make this closer to a [MCVE]? Because your example code doesn't do what you claim (it would make a `dict` equivalent to typing `mydict = {1: list_2}`), and it's unclear what your goal is.

Comment: No problem, just updated the question! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of problem is properly solved with a `collections.defaultdict(set)`; the `defaultdict` gives you easy auto-vivificaction of `set`s for each key on demand, and the `set` uniquifies the values associated with each key:

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(set)
for k, v in zip(list_1, list_2):
    mydict[k].add(v)
```

You can then convert the result to a plain `dict` with `list` values with:

```
mydict = {k: list(v) for k, v in mydict.items()}
```

If order of the values must be preserved, on modern Python you can use `dict`s instead of `set` (on older Python, you'd use `collections.OrderedDict`):

```
mydict = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in zip(list_1, list_2):
    mydict[k][v] = True  # Dummy value; we're using a dict to get an ordered set of the keys
```

with the conversion to plain `dict` with `list` values being unchanged

If the input is already sorted, `itertools.groupby` is theoretically slightly more efficient (it's actual `O(n)`, vs. average case `O(n)` using `dict`s), but in practice the `defaultdict` is typically as faster or faster (the implementation of `groupby` has some unavoidable inefficiencies). Just for illustration, the `groupby` solution would be:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

mydict = {k: {v for _, v in grp} for k, grp in groupby(zip(list_1, list_2), key=itemgetter(0))]

# Or preserving order of insertion:
getval = itemgetter(1)  # Construct once to avoid repeated construction
mydict = {k: list(dict.fromkeys(map(getval, grp)))
          for k, grp in groupby(zip(list_1, list_2), key=itemgetter(0))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a dictionary is a set it cant contain twice the same key but it can have the key once then a list of value for that you can use the one-line method

```py
my_dict = {key:[list_2[i] for i in range(len(list_2)) if list_1[i]==key] for key in set(list_1)}
```

Or a more classic method

```py
my_dict = {}
for key_id in range(len(list_1)):
    if list_1[key_id] not in my_dict:
        my_dict[list_1[key_id]] = []
    my_dict[list_1[key_id]].append(list_2[key_id])
```

In both case the result is

```py
my_dict = {1: ['x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'g', 'r', 't', 'w', 'r'], 2: ['r', 'r', 't', 'f', 'c', 'd']}
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(somesequence)):` that only uses `i` to index the sequence is an anti-pattern. You just wanted `for key, value in zip(list_1, list_2):`, replacing each use of `list_1[key_id]` with `key`, and `list_2[key_id]` with `value`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your key is too unique. there're only two unique keys 1 and 2. So if you're creating dictionaries you can't have {1:x, 1:y} at same time for example, unless you change the key to something new and unique.

I would use a tuple in your purpose:

```py
list(set(tuple(zip(list_1, list_2))))
```

The set gives you unique mappings which is what dropping the duplicates.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Sorry my question probably isn't as clear as it should be but the output I'm looking for would be one dictionary keyed by 1 and 2 with lists as values containing only the unique values for each ie:

dict = {1:[x,y,g,r,t,w],2:[r,t,f,c,d]}

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2] 

values = ['x','x','x','y','g','r','t','w','r','r','r','t','f','c','d'] 

result = {}

for key,value in  zip(keys,values):

  if key not in result:

    result[key] = []
    if value not in result[key]:
      result[key].append(value)
  else:

    if value not in result[key]:
      result[key].append(value)


print(result)
```

> {1: ['x', 'y', 'g', 'r', 't', 'w'], 2: ['r', 't', 'f', 'c', 'd']}

**Note:**

```
zip(keys,values) this will create a iterable of tuples, each tuple consist of one element from the keys and values.

(1,'x')
(1,'x')
```